# Google Analytics track transfer to sister site as not an "exit"?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two domains (i.e. example.com and foobar.com) and I have **separate** Google analytics properties for the two domains, but since I own the two (and they link to each other), I would like to know how many exits from one are really transfers to the other (and have them not really be "exits" from GA's perspective).

I know I can trigger an event on an outbound link, and I could do the math of "number of exits minus number of "sister site" events" to figure out the number, but it would be best if those transfers were simply not registered as exits at all.

Is there a way to flag an outbound link as "this is okay, they're not really leaving my family of sites" so it doesn't get marked as an "exit"?

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is known as cross domain tracking. You can see further details on that here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain, but the basics of it are that you need to have both sites defined under a single property, you can have multiple sites under a single property and can analyze them separately if you need but for the purposes of reporting on exists to other sites and transfers between sites you would need to have both sites under a single property to make it work properly.